# C# Unable to load DLL (Module could not be found HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

Tags: c#, c++, .net, visual-studio-2012, dll

error:Unable to load DLL 'x.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

OS: Windows 7

I have two stations, Visual Studio 2012, using .net 4.0; the other don't have VS installed
On the first station with VS2012 I have a C# solution with a C++ project imported.
I'm using:

```
    [DllImport("x.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
```

On this station is working.

But when I moved on the other station (that don't have VS installed) it appear that error.
If I install VS, it's working.

What are some possible reasons for this problem to occur? Any ideas on what I could be missing or how I could debug this problem?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The most likely reason is that the machine which does not have Visual Studio installed is missing the C++ runtime that is needed by your unmanaged DLL. Install the appropriate C++ runtime from the downloadable redistributable.

Do make sure that your unmanaged DLL is linked against the release runtime and not the debug runtime. The latter cannot be redistributed.

You can debug unmanaged DLL dependency issues using tools like Dependency Walker, Process Monitor etc.

Comment: I installed vcredist_x86_vs2012.exe. The same error. I will try with Dependency Walker

Comment: Then use Dependency Walker to debug the missing dependency. I would not be at all surprised if you had linked the DLL to the debug runtime.

Comment: I used Dependency Walker to debug the missing dependency and I observed that are missing these dlls: mfc110.dll, mfc111d.dll, msvcp110.dl, msvcp110d.dll, msvcr110.dll, msvcr110d.dll. Solution: I added these dlls in Release folder, now the program is working. I don't know why it can not see these dlls from SysWOW64. Do you have another solution?

Comment: You've linked to the debug runtime. You cannot redistribute that. Link against release runtime. Clearly you have dependency on mfc too. Need to resist that too.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem

1. Use Dependency Walker to check the missing dependencies
2. In my case, I was missing `msvcp110d.dll` and `msvcr110d.dll`
3. I copied these two files from my dev PC to test PC's `C:\Windows\SysWOW64`  PC and worked!
4. Also, you can add Visual Studio C++ 11.0 DebugCRT(x86) as a dependency in InstallShield to make it work